# android:excludeFromRecents does not work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have added `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml.

But if I just stay in my app, and click "Recent App" button, my app still shows in the recent apps list.

If I click "Back" button to Launcher, and click "Recent App" button, my app does not show in the recent apps.

It is a bug of Android, or do I need to add some others flags in AndroidManifest.xml? Thanks.